# Make document read only using docx-templates in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, readonly

I am trying to generate a docx document from a template using docx-templates in nextjs. Can anybody tell how to make the generated document readonly?
Or make parts of the document read-only?

I tried by writing into a secured document and the library successfully generated the document but the generated document was not read-only.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm install docx-templates docxtemplater jszip`

Create a template Word document (.docx) with the placeholders you want to fill. Placeholders should be defined using double curly braces, e.g., **{{placeholder}}**.

**Load the template in your React component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Docxtemplater } from 'docxtemplater';

class ReadOnlyDocument extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateReadOnlyDocument();
  }

  generateReadOnlyDocument = () => {
    const templateFilePath = '/path/to/your/template.docx';
    fetch(templateFilePath)
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((arrayBuffer) => {
        // Create a new Docxtemplater instance
        const docx = new Docxtemplater();

        // Load the template
        docx.loadZip(new JSZip(arrayBuffer));

        // Set options to make the document read-only
        const options = {
          isReadOnlyMode: true,
          // You can also set a password for write protection (optional):
          // password: 'yourPassword'
        };

        // Render the template
        docx.setData({/* Your data to fill in the placeholders */});
        docx.render();

        // Get the generated document as a Uint8Array
        const generatedDocument = docx.getZip().generate({ type: 'uint8array' });

        // Save the generated document or use it as needed
        // For example, you could send it to the client as a download link or display it using a PDF viewer.
        // fs.writeFileSync('/path/to/your/generatedDocument.docx', generatedDocument);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error generating the document:', error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Your React component content */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReadOnlyDocument;
```